# Handle HTML form submission with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having issues with a simple login page I am trying to make. It asks the user for a username and password and when login is pressed it should alert either success or fail, depending on whether the username and password are both admin. Currently when the login button is pressed the page just refreshes and the fields are cleared.

I would like to avoid having the javascript inline in the html file as I would rather have better separation.

```js
function Verify() {
    let loginForm = document.getElementById("loginForm")
    var passref = "admin"
    var userRef = "admin"

    loginForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        var username = document.getElementById("uname").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("pword").value;

        if (username == userRef || password == passref) {
            alert("Success")
        }
        else {
            alert("Fail")
        }

    });
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="loginForm">

    <div class="container">
        <label for="uname" id="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter username" id="uname" required>

        <label for="pword"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" id="pword" required>

        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me?
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="background-color: #f1f1f1;">
        <button type="button" class="cancelBtn">Cancel</button>
        <span class="forgot">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
    </div>

</form>
```

I have tried multiple tests to see if the code is even being called, and it looks like the function isn't being called. I have also tried an `<input>` for for the login button and does not work.

Comment: Seems you didn't include the script in the HTML, if you have call `Verify()` to add the listener

Comment: Why does your label _and_ your input share an id? That's not how IDs work, and would select the first element with that ID, in this case: a label. A `<label />` does not have a `value` like the `<input />` does. The code as it stands now also never calls `Verify`, so no event listeners are added to your form and therefor no alert is triggered, although this could just be an omission on your end? Unwrap the content of the `Verify` function, as it _itself_ does not even verify, it attaches a private method to an event listener that does.

Comment: *"it looks like the function isn't being called"* - Where in the code do you expect this function to be called and why?  Did you just forget to use the function anywhere?

Comment: Not your main problem, but another one: That OR (||) should be an AND (&&). (Also I guess you are aware that in a real situation this method of checking credentials in the frontend is not secure as the user can get in to see the code.)

Comment: A Haworth. Yes thanks for that spot, but now on a fail case the function is run properly. But I get the fail alert multiple times? Also yes, I am just using this to build my skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove your `label`s duplicate ID, unwrap the `Verify` method (or call it but it seems you don't want to add the listeners multiple times here anyway) and then make sure you fill in the required fields, it will start working as intended:

```js
const loginForm = document.getElementById("loginForm");
const passref = "admin";
const userRef = "admin";

loginForm.addEventListener( "submit", event => {

    event.preventDefault();
    
    const username = document.getElementById("uname").value;
    const password = document.getElementById("pword").value;
  
    // I presume you want both to match, so use `&&` AND
    // If you only want the username or password to match, use `||` OR
    if( username == userRef && password == passref ){
    
        alert( "Success" );
        
    } else {
    
        alert( "Fail" );
        
    }

});
```

```html
<form method="" id="loginForm">

    <div class="container">
        <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter username" id="uname" required>

        <label for="pword"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" id="pword" required>

        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me?
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="background-color: #f1f1f1;">
        <button type="button" class="cancelBtn">Cancel</button>
        <span class="forgot">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks this has fixed it and all works now. But now with a fail case, I get the fail alert twice, is there a reason for this?

Comment: I'm not getting that?

Comment: Are you including the scripts twice?

Comment: No I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

We can always discuss if it is a good idea to validate a login form on the front-end. That aside, you can use the [pattern attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) to validate the input elements. The form will only submit if the two input elements are valid. If you click the login button and the input elements are not valid a invalid event will be fired (or one for each invalid input element).

(I hope that you will give the user feedback, not using the alert box...)

```js
document.forms.loginform.addEventListener("submit", event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("Success");
});

document.forms.loginform.addEventListener("invalid", event => {
  //event.preventDefault();
  alert("Fail");
}, true);
```

```html
<form method="" id="loginform">
  <div class="container">
    <label>
      <b>Username</b>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter username" pattern="admin" required>
    </label>
    <label>
      <b>Password</b>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" pattern="admin" required>
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember">
      <span>Remember me?</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="container" style="background-color: #f1f1f1;">
    <button type="button" class="cancelBtn">Cancel</button>
    <span class="forgot">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
  </div>
</form>
```